# HTML window popup and proper degrade for iPad

Tags: javascript, html, ipad

I have a "quizzes" website where a list of quizzes is shown and each link opens a popup for a cute little quiz:

```
<a href="quizzes/stable-tachycardia.htm" target="_blank">Start quiz &raquo;</a>
```

On a desktop, I can have the user return to the quiz list with:

```
<a onClick="window.close()" href="#">Return to quizzes</a>
```

There's a couple of problems with this approach, and I'd like something better:

1. If the user arrived at this page with a `target="_blank"` link, then the "return" link should use `window.close` to get them back where they started
2. If the user agent ignores `target="_blank"` like iPad/Chrome then the "return" link should  do a normal hyperlink to `quizzes/index.htm`
3. If the user came into `quizzes/stable-tachycardia.htm` via a direct link, the "return" link should do a normal hyperlink

Is there a good solution that covers each use case?

Comment: Did you try using `window.open`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have it link to a JavaScript function which checks for the presence of `window.parent`.  If the parent window exists, open the desired URL in the parent and close the current window.  If there is no parent, just open the URL in the current window.